# how to fix i need to create a button to generate ticket and download that

Tags: php, html

how to fix i need to create a button to generate ticket and download that
sorry for my inglish am italiano
when button click genereat a image with personal information and then user can download the ticket

```
        $username="Mario";
        $password="test1234"
        echo "<form action='your_ticket.php' method='post'>";
        echo "<p>&nbsp;Username :$username&nbsp;</p>";
        echo "<p>&nbsp;Password :$password</p>";
        echo "<p>&nbsp;Ticket key :$ticketkey</p>";
        echo "<p>&nbsp; <button name='ticket'>Ticket Download</button></p>";
        echo "</form>";
    if (isset($_POST['ticket']) ){  

        $imgPath = 'images/ticket1.jpg';
        $$img= imagecreatefromjpeg($imgPath);
        $color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
    /*
    Nome
    */

        $stringnome = "Nome";  
        $fontSize = 32;
        $xnome = 115;
        $ynome = 380;
        imagestring($image, $fontSize, $xnome, $ynome, $stringnome , $color);

    /*
    Valido
    */

        $stringdate = "Valido fino 05/06/2020";  
        $xdate = 100;
        $ydate = 435;
        imagestring($image, $fontSize, $xdate, $ydate, $stringdate, $color);
    /*
    Ticket KEy
    */

        $stringkey = "15879465";  
        $xkey = 160;
        $ykey = 490;
        imagestring($image, $fontSize, $xkey, $ykey, $stringkey, $color);
    /*
    Acces
    */

        $stringacc= "Full";  
        $xacc = 118;
        $yacc = 543;
        imagestring($image, $fontSize, $xacc, $yacc, $stringacc, $color);




        header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
        imagejpeg($img);
        imagedestroy($img);
    }
```

Comment: What is the issue? ..

Comment: @hacker315 i use that like if button is clicked